# Flutter, создал .apk файл, который устанавливается, но не работает на телефоне

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

Создал приложение по отслеживанию криптовалют на фреймворке Flutter, язык Dart. Успешно запустил его на AVD, все работало прекрасно! Но после компиляции в .apk файл и переноса его на смартфон через FileManager:

1. Он установился
2. Запустился
3. Картинка отобразилась
4. Но... При нажатие кнопки обновить стоимость по нынешнему курсу, ничего не происходило.

В приложение данные берутся с coinmarketcup по http пакету.

Проблему выявить не могу. Думал дело в SDK, оказалось нет.
IDE Android Studio.

Comment: может быть дело в коде, а не в IDE? Flutter SDK позволяет запустить приложение в дев-режиме на реальном устройстве. Вы это делали?

Comment: Лог с устройства, версия андроида на устройстве? Ставка вслепую - http на 9 андроиде забыли разрешение прописать.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала запустите ваш проект в **debug** режиме, убедитесь что ваше приложение работает правильно (возможно у вас нет доступа к интернету, из-за этого не обрабатывается ошибка в **release** версии сборки). Потом попробуйте пересобрать ваш проект так:

```
flutter clean
flutter build apk --release
```